# how to parse a XML in C# using NamspaceManager,XML is having namespaces defined at elements level

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml

i wish to parse following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product xmlns="http://products.org"> 
    <make xmlns="http://camera.org">
 <model>Camry</model> 
</make>
 <make xmlns="http://tv.org">
   <model>Sony</model>
</make>
</product>
```

Code written to parse it

This is how i m writing Parsing Code

[image]
but in last i m getting null inxmlNode object.  Can u tell what more to do .

Comment: Please provide the value of pXMLElementPath,

Comment: it cud be /product or /make or

Comment: if you are including the "/" then that is the problem. The name of the nodes are "product" or "make".

Comment: @BitOff it compulsory to put slash in XPath expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ignore namespaces in XPath.*  The elements in your document all have non-blank namespace URI's.

Your question title indicates you're on the right track: you need to explicitly bind the URI's to prefixes using an XmlNamespaceManager, and use those prefixes in your path expressions.

This program is tested against your input document

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class XPathNamespace
{
    public static void Main() {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("test1.xml");

        XmlNamespaceManager xnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        xnm.AddNamespace("p", "http://products.org");
        xnm.AddNamespace("c", "http://camera.org");
        xnm.AddNamespace("t", "http://tv.org");

        ShowNode(doc.SelectSingleNode("/p:product", xnm));
        ShowNode(doc.SelectSingleNode("/p:product/c:make", xnm));
        ShowNode(doc.SelectSingleNode("/p:product/t:make", xnm));
    }

    private static void ShowNode(XmlNode node) {
        Console.WriteLine("<{0}> {1}",
                          node.LocalName, 
                          node.NamespaceURI);
    }
}
```

and it produces the following output

```
<product> http://products.org
<make> http://camera.org
<make> http://tv.org
```

Hope this helps.

(*) This doesn't mean you can't ignore the *exact* namespace in your XPath.  For example, you could match

```
/*[local-name()='product']
```

But that's a workaround and illustrates that you still have to deal with the presence of a namespace somehow or other.

Comment: very Good harpo , i m doing this in similar way. i can add Namespaces at runtime since i m having them in a dictionary object. But at runtime how can I came to know , that before my xpath expression whether i have to prefix p: , or c: , or t:

Comment: The prefix is arbitrary.  It just has to match the prefix used in your expression.  It sounds like you can create the prefixes serially (like `ns1`, `ns2`, and so on).  You'll have to build the XPath expressions to use the corresponding prefix.

Comment: @Abhishek, just populating the namespace manager doesn't change the result of your XPath, if you're not using the prefixes.  You can (apparently) add an entry with a blank prefix, but it won't cause the expression `/product` to work on your document.  You need to change the expression as well.  You'll also need to change the `String.Empty` to a default value before adding to the namespace manager in order to use it.

Comment: yes i understands wat u r explaining . but at runtime how can we know that among various prefixes which we should add

Comment: That's a domain problem :)  I mean, it's something only you can answer, from knowing how the document is constructed and what you want from it.  It's not a technical problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3260/discussion-between-abhishek-gupta-and-harpo)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example for you. Please have a look.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx